# The local does not work with docker and the openjdk image

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, locale

I found that my locale did not work on my production server.

I had put this image and the internalization worked:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN sed -i -e 's/# ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen
RUN sed -i -e 's/# fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen

RUN dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales
RUN update-locale LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
RUN update-locale LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8

ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE ru_RU:ru
ENV LC_ALL ru_RU.UTF-8

ENV LANG fr_FR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE fr_FR:fr
ENV LC_ALL fr_FR.UTF-8

RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=prod","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

but I want to simplify my image:

```
FROM openjdk:11

ENV TZ=Europe/Paris
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

ENV LANG fr_FR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE fr_FR:fr
ENV LC_ALL fr_FR.UTF-8
COPY target/*.jar /app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=prod","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

but I do not understand because on my spring boot pplication the local fr does not work.

I have messages.properties and messges_en.properties.

The local en works but not the fr.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have a `messages_fr.properties`?

Comment: no i have messages.properties and message_en.properties it works fine on my local pc and on the old ubuntu image

Comment: ok thank you it was the problem of not having mi messages_fr.properties

Comment: I'll add that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `messages_fr.properties` file.